# Invoke a listener in a specified function

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a `preferenceListener` in which i listen to changes in the preference

```
preferenceListener = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
                if (key.equals(SettingsActivity.CAR)
                         { }

                } 

             }
        };
```

But i want to invoke this listener in `onResume()` only. Means if the activity goes into `onResume()` and my preference is changed, then only i want to invoke this listener. How to achive this?

Comment: did you try overriding onResume() method and keeping the listener there?

Comment: @Nabin But a listener will respond anytime if i change a preference. If i define this listener in onCreate, it listens everytime the preference is changed and not only when my activity goes into onCreate

Comment: where did you used this post it?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin i am using in onCreateView in my fragment.I want to use in onResume() of same fragment.

Comment: @Diffy post you oncreateView

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FBS9kkAc
pasted the relevant part @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: @Diffy no I mean where did you used the `preferenceListener`?

Comment: I am registering this is onCreateView(). And when i change my prefernce in the SettingsActivity, the code here is invoked according to the changed preference @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: @Diffy that is why I asking to post your onCreateView

Comment: http://pastebin.com/9y2SqgZf
here it is @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: @Diffy so you want your listener to only work in OnResume?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your listener to be only used in the `onResume` then you can **add** and **remove** your listener using `unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to disable the listener from listening.

So in your `onresume` you register it and in your `onCreate` you can unregister/disable from listening

**sample:**

```
preferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceListener); //in onresume
preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(preferenceListener); //in oncreate
```